# Pass ValueTuple instead of arguments

Tags: c#, tuples, parameter-passing, valuetuple

Is it possible to do in this way (or maybe I need specific version of C#)?

```
Function<int,int,int,int> triSum = (a,b,c) => {return a+b+c;};
var tup = (1,2,3);
triSum(tup); //passing one tuple instead of multiple args
```

Update: I mean passing tuple instead of separate arguments.

```
public void DoWrite(string s1, string s2)
{
Console.WriteLine(s1+s2);
}
public (string,string) GetTuple()
{
//return some of them
}
//few lines later
DoWrite(GetTuple());
```

Comment: The short answer is no, this is not built into C#.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I've asked.

Comment: The answers here, and the duplicate, all rely on changing the delegate signature to be more in line with what you want to accomplish, but the `*xxx` parameter unpacking that you would find in Python does not exist in C#.

Comment: However, you *could*, although I would not recommend it, use this approach: `triSum.DynamicInvoke(Enumerable.Range(0, tup.Length).Select(i => tup[i]).ToArray());` This is only available in .NET Core 2.x+ I think, not in .NET Framework.

Comment: Kinda ugly, don't it?

Comment: Oh, seriously ugly, as I said, *I would not recommend it* :)

Answer (score 10):

Yes you could use *Named* *ValueTuples* C# 7.1 , or even just a *Local Method* if it suits

```
Action<(int a, int b, int c)> triSum = t 
   => Console.WriteLine(t.a + t.b + t.c);

triSum((1, 2, 3));
```

or just as a local method

```
void TriSum((int a, int b, int c) t)
   => Console.WriteLine(t.a + t.b + t.c);

TriSum((1, 2, 3));
```

Comment: I like you answer too. But why did you change `Func<int, int, int, int>` to `Action<(int, int, int)>`?

Comment: @Enigmativity I belive it was an action originally, or maybe I was imagining things

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
Func<(int a, int b, int c), int> triSum = x => { return x.a + x.b + x.c; };

var tup = (1, 2, 3);

var sum = triSum(tup);
```

Or more succinctly this:

```
Func<(int a, int b, int c), int> triSum = x => x.a + x.b + x.c;
```

Comment: Upvoting, as its probably more inline with what the OP wants

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in the code, in short the following works:

```
Func<Tuple<int,int,int>,int > triSum = a => { return a.Item1 + a.Item2 + a.Item3; };
Tuple<int,int,int> tup = new Tuple<int, int, int>(3,4,5);
triSum(tup); //passing one tuple instead of multiple args
```

Problems in the code above:

1. `Action` is a function delegate which returns `void`, so you should use `Func`
2. The way you passed parameters to Action make them three independent ints and not a tuple
3. Also the syntax var tup = (1,2) is from c# 7.0 onwards and cannot be used in older version (a nuget package is there though)

Comment: 1. Thanks, fixed. 2. And that's a main question - passing valuetuple into places which waiting for separate arguments. 3. Not a problem. I mean maybe I need some C#8 or specific package etc. to achieve asked behavior?

Comment: @TrolltheLegacy Each tuple is a different type, it is not possible for a compiler to substitute a number of ints with a tuple having same number of ints. You will have to modify the function definition to make it explicitly as a tuple

Comment: And that's must be an answer.